# android listen to application launch

Tags: android

I saw at the play store that there are some apps that do "app locking". 
Before an app is launched, the app locker app opens it's own activity and ask for a passcode.
at first i thought that it listen to some broadcast that the Launcher sends, but as i read over the net, it's impossible.
I saw other people asking about it, and they suggested to sniff the logcat and look for a "start activity" log, but it sounds like a bad idea...
Other option is to loop over the package manager's getInstalledApps and always get the first app (which means that it's the app in the foreground), and then probably launch my activity.

So, I wonder how these apps work? are they using the framework API or some low level system API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of apps run a service in background and checks top activity in a loop continuously (or with short delays like 100ms). If top running activity's package is not same with let's say lockerapp, it launches it own pin activity.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
```

Comment: Can you suggest some link to this argument? In particular how to distinguish which app is launched and its details (e.g. if Android Settings, which module: security, Wi-Fi and so on).